# Understanding output from sitk.GetSpacing()

Tags: simpleitk

Can anyone explain me the meaning of the output that is generated from sitk.GetSpacing(). Also could anyone conform if I understood the concept of image spacing correctly, does it just mean the co-ordinate system for the image?

Comment: I think I got it, is it the size of each pixel? The output that I get is in the form of [1,1,1] for a RGB image. Does it mean that each pixel size is 1 X 1 X 1 and the unit is same as the size of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a spacing of [1,1,1] means that the pixels (voxels, really) are cubic, i.e., the same size in the X, Y, and Z dimensions.